# Invoice date is in GMT/UTC when programmatically creating an invoice

Tags: magento, invoices

We have a process that generates shipments every 4 hours. Only the items that are shipped should be invoiced, so invoice creation is part of this process.

This process runs in an external PHP script that loads the Magento environment and then processes the pending orders.

When the invoices are created, the create at time is off by 4 hours, so that looks like it's not using the store time.  I've reviewed the Magento code and searched the web, but, I don't see any indication that you should do something to set the correct store time when creating an invoice.

At the top of the script the timezone to the store's timezone -

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Boston');
```

The magento environment based on the order's store id -

```
//Start environment emulation of the specified store
$storeId = $order->getStoreId();
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
```

Later, for order that shipment, an invoice is created -

```
// create an invoice for the invoiceable items
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($toInvoice);

if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invoice generation failed - no items to invoice.'));
}

$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();

$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
$transactionSave->save();

$invoiceID = $invoice->getIncrementId();
```

Any suggestions what should be done differently?

Thanks!

Comment: Mangeto saves the datetime values as UTC. Aren't the dates correct on *retrieval*? See this: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/guide-through-magentos-timezones/

Comment: It's odd, the datetime value in the database is not the GMT time, but the actual order time in EST. So when the data is fetched it's off by 4 hours.  The thing is I have the practically the same code running in an observer and the time is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all dates in Magento are stored as GMT.

Check this file for methods that will help you when working with dates in Magento app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Date.php

Answer (score 0):

I read inchoo article from above and I make conclusion:
Just use formatDate() and formatTime() methods when you want to display dates and times and don't worry about anything else.